# Linux and Bluetooth - Why does Bluez doesn't like DBus?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, dbus, bluez

I've been trying to connect a bluetooth dongle to a bt breakout board using a Raspberry Pi(kernel 3.12). Both of them show up with hcitool scan and dev. I've already installed bluez5 that keeps complaining about dbus:

```
$ bluez-simple-agent hci0 20:14:03:24:37:06
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent", line 89, in <module>
    manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/"),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.bluez was not provided by any .service files
```

I can restart DBus but when trying to update I get funky messages:

```
~ $ sudo /etc/init.d/dbus restart
[ ok ] Stopping system message bus: dbus.
[ ok ] Starting system message bus: dbus.
~ $ sudo update-rc.d -f dbus defaults
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (empty) of script `dbus' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
insserv: warning: script 'mathkernel' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

I've tried to re-install DBus bit I get errors at ./configure:

http://pastebin.com/tihTMxan

Comment: issue is not in dbus, its in bluez, is bluetoothd running in pi, error logs as "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.bluez was not provided by any .service files" means that bluez does not get registered with dbus

Comment: Thank you ashish, any idea how could I get the .service files registered by dbus?

Comment: Check if bluetoothd is running or not,check with dbus introspect if bluez is registered , if not compile adn run bluez